# how to parallelize a dot product with MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, message-passing

I've been trying to learn MPI and I've this code snippet from C which should be formatted to MPI to make it parallizable;

```
// this is a dot product
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;

for (int i=0 ; i<100000; i++){
    c += A[i] * B[i];
}
```

Im kinda confused of how to deal with for-loops when using MPI but this is my answer to the exercise;

```
// this is a dot product
int A[100000];
int B[100000];
int C=0;
int rootId = 0;
int  numtasks, taskId, len, partner, message;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);    

for (int i=0 ; i<100000; i++){
    c = A[i] * B[i];

    if(rootId == taskid){
        MPI_Send(&A[100000], &B[100000], MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPP_COMM_WORLD, MPI_Status)

    }else if (rootId < taskId){
        MPI_Recv(C, 100000, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPP_COMM_WORLD, MPI_Status)
    }

    MPI_Finalize(); return 0;

}
```

Im not sure if this even correct, but I believe im in the right direction...

The problem about MPI is that I can't really find good examples of how to rewrite or structe it with loops - There are some examples in fortran but this is nothing im familiar with...
I've only seen simple examples of "Hello world" C in MPI....  But nothing useful to get from there.

All help would be appreciated..

Comment: I guess, you are looking for something similar to this one ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45677220/how-to-implement-a-mpi-filter-on-c-code/45736526#45736526

Comment: I didn't find the answer in that thread sufficient... too complicated if you ask me. With the delta and reminder variables.. I believe it can be simplified much easier...

Answer (score 0):

was there a typo and did you mean instead ?

```
for (int i=0 ; i<100000; i++){
    c += A[i] * B[i];
}
```

parallelization heavily depends on how your arrays `A` and `B` are distributed.

the simplest case, which is also the one with the biggest memory footprint, is to have the full arrays `A` and `B` on all MPI tasks.
based on a task rank and the total number of tasks, each task can compute a part of the dot product e.g.

```
for (int i=start; i<end; i++) {
    c += A[i] * B[i];
}
```

and then you can `MPI_Reduce()/MPI_Allreduce()` with `MPI_SUM` the partial dot products in order to get the final result.

Comment: Yes i meant c += sorry about that...

I get the part for recent the MPI_SUM and this can be used to fetch the SUM... Thanks for that
But how about my code? Im interested of how I programmed the send and receive part and if this is done correctly

Comment: your `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` is obviously wrong since `MPI_Status` is a type. it should be replaced with `status` in the receive, and there are no such things in the send. `C` is a scalar, so you cannot receive `10000 MPI_INT`. if you want to send the full array `A`, you can `MPI_Send(A, 10000, MPI_INT, dest, tag, communicator)`. but you'd rather `MPI_Scatter[v]()` it or simply `MPI_Bcast()` it. if you still want to use `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`, please edit your post, add some comments to clearly explain the algorithm in plain English, and i will try to help you from that.

Comment: Could you maybe illustrate of how you would format this to MPI?
So I can understand it better? thanks

Comment: if you want some help with `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`, please describe your algorithm in plain English. if you need some help with `MPI_Reduce()` or other collectives, then once again, please write an algorithm in plain English, write a bit of code, and if it fails, then i will try to help you. if you are simply hoping to get your homework done, the best i can do to help you ... is not helping you at all.

Comment: I see, no its not like im hoping to get my homework done by others, It could be more of hints or reference of code which I can reflect on... I mean there isn't much of code formatting from C -> Mpi anywhere on the internet... So its pretty difficult to get a hold of this, and understand it.... As described in the question... But I just want to know If I handle this wrongly and instead I should use some other MPI operations? such as MPI_Bcast() ... or other ways of handling the formatting

Comment: `C` is a language, `MPI` is a library. what you are looking for is resources on how to learn Parallel Programming (e.g. how to turn a sequential algo into a parallel one). there are plenty of resources available on the internet or in any bookstore. Then `MPI` is just one way among others to implement parallel programming, just like `C` is one language among other to write a program. and once again , `C` and `MPI` are heavily documented in both the internet or any bookstore.

Comment: Well, not very understandable if you ask me, and not with good examples.... But Thanks.. I will try to come up with a new algorithm and then demonstrate it for you with comments .

Comment: This is a very good book - and among the source files on the website there should be the dot product: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~peter/ppmpi/ .